# How to get a JPanel to show over the others in the same area

Tags: java, swing, awt, jpanel, layout-manager

So I am writing a little app that needs to have one JPanel be added to the same area as another and have one show up when it's needed - AKA when a button is pressed, one disappears and the other shows up. As soon as I have time, I will clean up the post, but for now I kinda need to rush so I don't miss the bus home.

Also, if this is not possible, please tell me a way I can replicate the effect. Preferably within the same window.

SSCCE ex. imports:

```
public class Demo implements ActionListener {
    static JButton switch = new JButton("Switch");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame disp = new JFrame("Demo");
        disp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        disp.add(switch, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JPanel pan1 = new JPanel();
        pan1.setBackground(Color.RED);
        disp.add(pan1);
        JPanel pan2 = new JPanel();
        pan2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        disp.add(pan2);
        disp.setVisible(true);
    }

    void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.paramString());
        //Something to switch the JPanels when "switch" is pressed
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to change the visibility of the button?

Comment: My apologies re. the earlier comment/edit. :P  It seems that is an *SSCCE ex imports*.  Not quite an SSCCE, but the next best thing.

Comment: As i said in the post, I was kinda rushed. It didn't occur to me to include the imports... My bad :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson After all this time, I JUST realized that you made the webpage to describe and try to popularize the term "SSCCE"... Nice job doing so!

Comment: Thank you.  I think that going through the process of making that short example has helped many people over the years - and hopefully many more in the future.  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson It probably has already helped many, many people... Great job on the website, by the way.

Comment: @RomanC I don't... What I wanted to do was make one panel appear, and have which one is showing toggle when you click `switch`.

Comment: @NickHartley You had to do it on time, how can I help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think what you want is to use one JPanel with a CardLayout.  This in turn could hold the other two colored JPanels.  You can then toggle between the two.  The JPanel with the CardLayout could then be added to your BorderLayout.CENTER.

The other option is to manage this yourself.  Keep references to both pan1 and pan2 as member variables.  Then inside of action performed, you can simply remove pan1 and add pan2.

Comment: Drop your last remark. Because setting the layoutManager on a JFrame is a shortcut to set it on the contentpane . Btw, the default layoutManager of a JFrame/Contentpane is BorderLayout.

Comment: Good catch - you are correct.  They changed that in Java 1.5.  In 1.4, you had to call getContentPane().setLayout().  I guess that shows how long it has been since I've done Swing.

Comment: Would the CardLayout still work with more than one variable? A link to a tutorial or the javadocs would be swell, too.

Comment: Yes, a CardLayout basically works like a deck of flash cards.  Each component you add can have entirely different content, it sizes them all to the same size and allows you to flip between them with methods like first(), next(), previous(), and show().  It's great for implementing "wizard" type interactions.

Comment: Can you think of any good tutorials on CardLayouts? I looked at the JavaDocs but they are REALLY obtuse and difficult to use.

Comment: Here is a tutorial on all of the Swing layouts.  Each layout (including CardLayout) has a link to its own tutorial  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.htm

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for [JFrame.setContentPane()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setContentPane%28java.awt.Container%29)

I think the method signature is pretty much self-explanatory.